# How to call template so rsyslog 8 creates one log file per client

Tags: rsyslog

I'm using **rsyslog 8.22** to receive syslog data sent from client hosts.
My goal is to have one log file created per client.

I've found a lot of data on older versions of rsyslog, but the change in configuration syntax has thrown me.

This configuration proves rsyslog is working, but aggregates all entries into one file:

```
if $fromhost-ip startswith '192.168.117.' then {
    action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/network.log")
    stop
}
```

(The rest of my `/etc/rsyslog.conf` is default.)

The following is not working. (No file is created):

```
template (name="DynFile" type="string" string="/var/log/network-%fromhost-ip%.log")
if $fromhost-ip startswith '192.168.117.' then {
    action(type="omfile" file="DynFile")
    stop
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fix is to specify `dynaFile`  in the **action** argument (not `file`).

```
template (name="DynFile" type="string" string="/var/log/network-%fromhost-ip%.log")
if $fromhost-ip startswith '192.168.117.' then {
    action(type="omfile" dynaFile="DynFile")
    stop
}
```

This creates the expected results:

```
$ ls -l /var/log/network/    
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root       286 Oct  4 13:21 192.168.117.21.log    
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root       284 Oct  4 13:25 192.168.117.22.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root       184 Oct  4 13:32 192.168.117.27.log
$
```

Comment: There is an error in this answer. According to the template all the files are put in the folder /var/log and the filenames are network-IPADDRESS.log whereas in your example the files are put in the subfolder /var/log/network and the filenames are just IPADDRESS.log without the network- prefix.